# Configuring WebSolr on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, solr, websolr

I have get the add on on heroku application, and added required sunspot gem in Gemfile and there is `WEBSOLR_URL` value in heroku config variables.

The `sunspot.yml` has also been added and the production settings is some thing like this production:

```
solr:
  hostname: <%=ENV["WEBSOLR_URL"]%>
  port: 8983
  log_level: WARNING
```

but still search is getting crash on heroku with this error

```
RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
2012-01-18T05:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.28 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /solr/KEY_m0/select</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/solr/a55_m0/select</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource (/solr/KEY_m0/select) is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.28</
```

P.S.
I have replaced the actual api key with KEY word.

Comment: The 404 sounds like something you want to report at http://help.websolr.com/ if you haven't already. Though, for starters, websolr runs on port 80 rather than 8983.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can embed ERB tags into your sunspot.yml file - the line `<%=ENV["WEBSOLR_URL"]%>` is probably getting parsed literally.

I'm looking at my sunspot.yml for a heroku app I'm running, and it looks like I don't really have any settings for production at all. So long as heroku's WEBSOLR_URL is set correctly, I think that overrides the sunspot.yml anyway. I'd try removing that concat tag altogether; it might be what's tripping things up.

Comment: Sunspot will indeed detect and use the `WEBSOLR_URL` or `SOLR_URL` environment variables.

Comment: @NickZadrozny do i need to reindex the in production mode too. Is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: @Mark Tabler I have localhost instead of ENV["WEBSOLR_URL"] is it the cause of this problem ?

Comment: @Rodrigo It's certainly a possibility.  "localhost" is always going to try to resolve to the local server, so unless you're running Solr on the same server as your web app, then it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Go to heroku dashboard and open your application. You will have your cobalt add-on there. When you click it for more details it will redirect you to websolr page where you can get your configuration instruction for heroku.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just had selected the wrong "index type" on my websolr index configuration so the issue was solved after selecting the one my app was actually using (Sunspot 2.0 for Ruby on Rails).

Answer (score 0):

Some time we might need to change the index type from Heroku Solr dashboard, we need to select -

- sunspot 2.0 for Ruby on Rails (Solr 4)